# Aproximation in the central difference formula

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, lipschitz-functions

I need help to solve the following problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5AKI.jpg)

The exercise suggests following the idea of the proof of Lemma 2.4.2 which says the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBdVj.jpg)

Following the ideas of the lemma, I try to prove the inequality given in the hint

$f(z)-f(x)=\int_{x}^{z}f'(y)dy$

$f(z)-f(x)-f'(x)(z-x)=\int_{x}^{z}[f'(y)-f'(x)]dy$

$f(z)-f(x)-f'(x)(z-x)-\frac{f''(x)(z-x)^2}{2}=\int_{x}^{z}[f'(y)-f'(x)-\frac{f''(x)(z-x)}{2}]dy$

From here I do not know how to continue, I am not sure if I should make the same change of variable as in $lemma 2.4.2$ and I do not know how to use the condition that the function $f ''$ is Lipschitz.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: In your last equation the derivative of the square is wrong. Also, it should not be a constant relative to the integration variable.

Comment: But I am following the steps of the lemma that is as a suggestion, also I do not see the error you mention, could you help me?

Comment: You have $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-x)^2}{2}=(z-x)$. In the FTC formulation that gives $\frac{(z-x)^2}{2}=\int_x^z(y-x)\,dy$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood your correction and I was able to finish the exercise. Thank you very much!